# Creating network visualization dashboards

Tags: networking, visualization, dashboard

I'm a Network Engineer, I want to create a custom data network visualization dashboard that includes interactive charts and graphs with drill down options and such. I'm a bit overwhelmed by the proliferation of languages and different ways of accomplishing this. What are some languages/libraries I should learn to accomplish this task, as well as good tutorials for your recommendations. I have intermediate coding experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using D3js, force directed graph is perfect for creating a network visualization, there are some examples here: [D3 force directed graph](http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/)